Keras 3 only supports V3 `.keras` files and legacy H5 format files (`.h5` extension). How to fix this bug?
ValueError: File format not supported: filepath=C:\Users\fedmor\Desktop\AI\resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1 (1). Keras 3 only supports V3 .keras files and legacy H5 format files (.h5 extension). Note that the legacy SavedModel format is not supported by load_model() in Keras 3. In order to reload a TensorFlow SavedModel as an inference-only layer in Keras 3, use keras.layers.TFSMLayer(C:\Users\fedmor\Desktop\AI\resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1 (1), call_endpoint='serving_default') (note that your call_endpoint might have a different name).
This is the problem that I`ve got. Idk what to do with this, do you guys have anu ideas?
I didt try to do anything. At this point Im just lost

I solved the problem by saving the model as (.h5) file instead of (.hdf5) and make sure to call the absolute path

Install tf_keras before using it.
import tf_keras as k3

model = k3.models.load_model(YOUR_MODEL_PATH)

